# Sonar 3.6.1 Unable to request: /batch_bootstrap/properties

Tags: timeout, sonarqube

We have Jenkins 1.509.2 + Sonar 3.6.1. And receive the below error, We didn't have the same error with Sonar 3.4.1 from which we upgraded. Could you advise how can we fix the issue?

```
Exception in thread "main" org.sonar.runner.RunnerException: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Unable to request: /batch_bootstrap/properties
 at org.sonar.runner.Runner.delegateExecution(Runner.java:288)
 at org.sonar.runner.Runner.execute(Runner.java:151)
 at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:84)
 at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:56)
Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Unable to request: /batch_bootstrap/properties
 at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ServerClient.request(ServerClient.java:82)
 at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ServerClient.request(ServerClient.java:72)
 at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchSettings.downloadSettings(BatchSettings.java:96)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
 at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
 at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
 at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
```

The error is not received every time - more like 90%. After I have upgraded all the Installed plugins, the error disappeared, on the next day - it appeared again. 
It appears for ALL the projects, small and big. The Jenkins server is far (network wise) - from the Sonar server on most of the projects, but we also have projects that are in the same location with Sonar - and still receive this issue. Is there a workaround at least to increase the timeout?

Comment: This issue should have been fixed by https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-4140. How big is your project? And how many projects do you have on your SonarQube instance?

Comment: I have around 20 projects, with 6 very active projects. I have small and big projects that have the same issue.

Comment: Do you get this error everytime? Is it always on the same project? Is the analysis run on a computer/server that is far (from a network point of view) from the SonarQube server? (please edit your question to provide those answers)

Comment: Edited the initial message.

Comment: I have installed Wireshark on Sonar server.The Sonar server receives  requests from Jenkins. Therefore it's not a network issue. The packets are being sent and received on both sides.

Comment: Can you download the content of the "/batch_bootstrap/properties" URL and tell us how long it take and the size of the file? (you can do it in a browser or using curl for instance)

Comment: It downloaded in 3 seconds or so, I just entered https://my_sonar_server/batch_bootstrap/properties directly into the browser

Comment: Have you modified your architecture during the upgrade to Sonar 3.6.1? I mean, could it be possible to the machine that hosts the web server and the DB is intermittently overloaded by other processes that eat CPU & RAM?

Comment: The upgrade was done on the same server on which the old Sonar was residing.

Comment: Could you activate the DEBUG logs in the "conf/logback.xml" file of your SonarQube server (you need to restart it) and check teh SQL requests that are called when this URL is called (see the following comment: https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-4140?focusedCommentId=320025&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-320025)

Comment: I have restarted Sonar, and started my project from Jenkins, this is the only debug message that was received after that, and the project failed with the same error.

INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/07/26 14:51:50 | 2013-07-26 14:51:50.405:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@MDCH-SP-SONAR:8080
2013.07.26 14:52:42 DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL  select top 1 notificati0_.id as id24_, notificati0_.created_at as created2_24_, notificati0_.data as data24_ from notifications notificati0_ order by notificati0_.created_at ASC

Comment: P.S. This is what I edited in logback.xml

<logger name="org.hibernate.SQL">
    <level value="DEBUG"/>
  </logger>
  <logger name="org.apache.ibatis">
    <level value="DEBUG"/>
  </logger>
  <logger name="java.sql">
    <level value="DEBUG"/>
  </logger>
  <logger name="java.sql.ResultSet">
    <level value="DEBUG"/>
  </logger>

  <logger name="org.sonar.MEASURE_FILTER">
    <level value="DEBUG"/>
  </logger>

Comment: Could you please paste the log inside your question? It is difficult to read it in a comment. Thanks.

Comment: @StasPl you should also set the logger "rails" to "DEBUG"

Comment: Are you still facing this issue or can you share how you got it solved? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We are seeing a similar error after upgrading from 3.4.1 to 3.6. The problem is not as severe as your (maybe 30% rather than 90%). Like your experience it is not limited to one project (errors in 2 out of every 7 builds). Restarting Sonar seems to help but does not always make it go away. Also, call me crazy but adding a -X flag to the maven build command has so far been the most reliable workaround. FYI, our builds are running on the same machine as the Sonar server (and the MySQL server).